# How can I unpack a slice as a partial function argument?

Tags: go

I'm using `exec.Command` that receives a variable number of strings for its second parameter. For example:

```
out, err = exec.Command("python3", "script_name.py", "argument", "--flag", "--another")
```

I can also use a slice and unpack it using `...`:

```
var args = []string{"script_name.py", "argument", "--flag", "--another"}
out, err = exec.Command("python3", args...)
```

BUT mixing the two does not work:

```
var args = []string{"argument", "--flag", "--another"}
out, err = exec.Command("python3", "script_name.py", args...)
```

fails with:

```
./tester.go:12:29: too many arguments in call to exec.Command
        have (string, string, []string...)
        want (string, ...string)
```

This is surprising to me since something similar would work in python.
I've tried looking for this specific case but most of the resources I found are just about slicing in general. I've "solved" it (more like a workaround) by prepending the "constant" part to the start of the slice, but wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything:

```
var args = os.Args
args = append([]string{"script_name.py"}, args...)
out, err := exec.Command("python3", args...).Output()
```

1. Am I missing anything? Is there a way to pass both the constant string and the unpacked array?
2. What are the language constraints here? Why is it distinguishing between `string, string, string` and `string, string...`? I'd love to understand this more deeply.

Comment: "This is surprising to me since something similar would work in python". A **lot** of things work in Python and don't in Go. That should not be a surprise.

Comment: The general rule is simple. Question: "Does Go provide shortcut/sugar/tooling/syntax/etc for ... as does JavaScrip, Python, Ruby, C#, etc?" Answer: "No."

Comment: But this is exactly sugar, just done in a confusing way. I would label this a "wat". Anyways, I got my answer which is all I care about. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: This is not sugar. There is exactly _one_ _way_ for variadic arguments in Go.

Comment: Reading about it more, you're right, it is not sugar. I still hold the opinion it could have been executed better though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No.
2. The constraints are detailed [in the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters):

> If the final argument is assignable to a slice type []T and is followed by ..., it is passed unchanged as the value for a ...T parameter.

That is the *only* case in which you can explode a slice into a variadic parameter, as you have found.

Comment: I find the spec not very straightforward about this behavior: in a function call as the one in the OP `f("foo", "bar", args...)`, `args` **is** the final argument, assignable to `[]T` and followed by `...`

Comment: @blackgreen but it is not. The signature is `func Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd`, meaning that `"bar", args...` are both being passed as `arg`, and therefore cannot be passed unchanged to the `...T` parameter.

Comment: To explain why the code in the OP doesn't work, I think you'd need to expand your quote by including a sentence from a couple lines above: — *"whose successive elements are the actual arguments, which all must be assignable to T."*. So with a signature including the parameter `...string`, the OP can't pass `"bar"` and `args...` because those "*successive elements*" are not all assignable to `string`. One is `string` and the other is `[]string`. This is the missing logical connection.

Comment: I disagree, because in context, the user does not interpret `args...` as `[]string` but as the explosion of its elements. The spec section I've quoted highlights that this is only possible if the argument can be passed unchanged, which seems to have been the missing logical connection given that OP accepted the answer.